# High Sierra How to See User Library

Tags: plist

I cannot save Contacts in High Sierra. I have tried following instructions for deleting the .plist in the User Library, but there is no "Show Library" option within the Finder's View>Show View Options.

Any advice? I'm unable to locate the .plist and unable to save contacts...

Comment: What happens when you try to save contacts? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal, type `open ~/Library`. This will open the user's Library folder.

To use the Finder:

- Open a Finder window and select "Home" from the Go menu
- Then selected "Show View Options" from the View menu
- Tick the "Show Library Folder" option

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to use a Terminal to open the User Library folder. For security reasons, the Library is hidden by default.

[image: Open-user-Library]

- In the Finder, click the Go menu in the menu bar
- **Press** and **hold the Option key (alt)**, Library shows up
- Go to e.g. Preferences > Select/delete your *.plist file you’re looking for.

! Be careful, make sure you do have a backup prior deleting preferences.